# SAP Cloud SDK Jenkins pipeline s4sdk-pipeline.groovy - production deployment step is skipped

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, sap-cloud-sdk

I have setup Jenkins project piper (https://sap.github.io/jenkins-library/). I have then setup a basic SAP Cloud Application Programming model app with integration for the SAP Cloud SDK pipeline with default configuration and uncommented the 'productionDeployment' stage and completed cloud foundry endpoints/orgs/spaces etc. I have committed the applicatino to the master branch in the git repo.

The pipeline executes successfully but is skipping the production deployment step.

[Pipeline execution results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmmhP.png)

When checking the logs I see:

```
[Pipeline] // stageenter code here
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Production Deployment)
Stage "Production Deployment" skipped due to when conditional
```

When I look at the script (https://github.com/SAP/cloud-s4-sdk-pipeline/blob/master/s4sdk-pipeline.groovy) I see:

```
        stage('Production Deployment') {
        *when { expression { commonPipelineEnvironment.configuration.runStage.PRODUCTION_DEPLOYMENT }* }
        //milestone 80 is set in stageProductionDeployment
        steps { stageProductionDeployment script: this }
    }
```

Can anyone explain what is required to pass the *commonPipelineEnvironment.configuration.runStage.PRODUCTION_DEPLOYMENT* check in order to execute the stageProductionDeployment script?

My pipeline_config.yml file (anonymized) is:

```
###
# This file configures the SAP Cloud SDK Continuous Delivery pipeline of your project.
# For a reference of the configuration concept and available options, please have a look into its documentation.
#
# The documentation for the most recent pipeline version can always be found at:
#    https://github.com/SAP/cloud-s4-sdk-pipeline/blob/master/configuration.md
# If you are using a fixed version of the pipeline, please make sure to view the corresponding version from the tag
# list of GitHub (e.g. "v15" when you configured pipelineVersion = "v15" in the Jenkinsfile).
#
# For general information on how to get started with Continuous Delivery, visit:
#    https://blogs.sap.com/2017/09/20/continuous-integration-and-delivery
#
# We aim to keep the pipeline configuration as stable as possible. However, major changes might also imply breaking
# changes in the configuration. Before doing an update, please check the the release notes of all intermediate releases
# and adapt this file if necessary.
#
# This is a YAML-file. YAML is a indentation-sensitive file format. Please make sure to properly indent changes to it.
###



### General project setup
general:
  productiveBranch: 'master'


### Step-specific configuration
steps:
  setupCommonPipelineEnvironment:
    collectTelemetryData: true

  cloudFoundryDeploy:
    dockerImage: 'ppiper/cf-cli'
    smokeTestStatusCode: '200'
    cloudFoundry:
      org: 'XXXXXX'
      space: 'XXXXXX'
      appName: 'MTBookshopNode'
      manifest: 'mta.yaml'
      credentialsId: 'CF_CREDENTIALSID'
      apiEndpoint: 'https://api.cf.XX10.hana.ondemand.com'

### Stage-specific configuration
stages:

  # This exclude is required for the example project to be successful in the pipeline
  # Remove it when you have added your first test
  s4SdkQualityChecks:
    jacocoExcludes:
      - '**/OrdersService.class'

#  integrationTests:
#    credentials:
#      - alias: 'mySystemAlias'
#        credentialId: 'mySystemCredentialsId'

#  s4SdkQualityChecks:
#    nonErpDestinations:
#      - 'myCustomDestination'

  productionDeployment:
    cfTargets:
      - org: 'XXXXXX'
        space: 'XXXXXX'
        apiEndpoint: 'https://api.cf.XX10.hana.ondemand.com'
        appName: 'myAppName'
        manifest: 'mta.yaml'
        credentialsId: 'CF_CREDENTIALSID'
```

My Jenkins file is unchanged:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

/*
 * This file bootstraps the codified Continuous Delivery pipeline for extensions of SAP solutions, such as SAP S/4HANA.
 * The pipeline helps you to deliver software changes quickly and in a reliable manner.
 * A suitable Jenkins instance is required to run the pipeline.
 * The Jenkins can easily be bootstraped using the life-cycle script located inside the 'cx-server' directory.
 *
 * More information on getting started with Continuous Delivery can be found in the following places:
 *   - GitHub repository: https://github.com/SAP/cloud-s4-sdk-pipeline
 *   - Blog Post: https://blogs.sap.com/2017/09/20/continuous-integration-and-delivery
 */

/*
 * Set pipelineVersion to a fixed released version (e.g. "v15") when running in a productive environment.
 * To find out about available versions and release notes, visit: https://github.com/SAP/cloud-s4-sdk-pipeline/releases
 */
String pipelineVersion = "master"

node {
    deleteDir()
    sh "git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/SAP/cloud-s4-sdk-pipeline.git -b ${pipelineVersion} pipelines"
    load './pipelines/s4sdk-pipeline.groovy'
}
```

Any ideas what I am missing for a production deployment and how I get through this check in the script for production deployment?

Regards
Neil

Comment: My guess it is because of the branch or its detection. Could you please tell us which kind of Jenkins Job (e.g., MultiBranch Pipeline) you are using? If MultiBranch Pipeline, is the log output from the master branch?

Comment: Hello Neil, did Daniel's answer resolve your issue? If so, kindly provide an answer for other community members who might come across this issue. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Daniel. There is only one branch at the moment in the Git repo (master) and its a simple 'pipeline' in Jenkins.

Comment: Hi Neil, you have to use the job type "multibranch pipeline". See: https://blogs.sap.com/2017/09/20/continuous-integration-and-delivery/

Answer (score 1):

the pipeline was built for multi-branch pipelines and will not work correctly in a single-branch pipeline job. There is no problem with running a project that has a single branch in a multi-branch pipeline job. To avoid confusion, we added a check to the pipeline in a recent version as documented here https://blogs.sap.com/2019/11/21/new-versions-of-sap-cloud-sdk-3.8.0-for-java-1.13.1-for-javascript-and-v26-of-continuous-delivery-toolkit/#cd-toolkit

Kind regards

Florian

Comment: Hi Florian
Thanks for the clarification. I was using this documentation https://sap.github.io/jenkins-library/guidedtour/ which mentions to select 'Pipeline' in Jenkins (not a multi-brach pipeline). Perhaps this could be updated as well?

Comment: The section of this documentation you refer to does not describe SAP Cloud SDK Pipeline. I see how this can be confusing. Thanks for pointing out where the confusion originated.

Comment: Perhaps this page https://sap.github.io/jenkins-library/scenarios/CAP_Scenario/ where it mentions configuring the productionDeployment stage (just before heading of Legacy documentation) could be updated to mention that production deployment only works in a multi-branch pipeline?